# List of userids without duplicates in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to get the list of userids from parent and its immediate children tracked by the **children** field in the parent document.

```
{
 _id:ObjectId("54d84f3ae4b0f922899b19cb"),
 userIds:["AAA","BBB","CCC"],
 children:[
           ObjectId("54d84f3ae4b0f922899b19cd"),
           ObjectId("54d84f3ae4b0f922899b19ce")
          ],
 category:"admin" 
}

{
 _id:ObjectId("54d84f3ae4b0f922899b19cd"),
 userIds:["AAA","EEE","FFF"],
 category:"admin" 

}

{
 _id:ObjectId("54d84f3ae4b0f922899b19ce"),
 userIds:["CCC","HHH"],
 category:"admin" 
}


  {
 _id:ObjectId("54d84f3ae4b0f922899b19cf"),
 userIds:["XXX","YYY"],
 category:"admin" 
}
```

How can i get the result of userids like below and should not get the ["XXX","YYY"] because it is not in the children array list?

```
["AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE","FFF","HHH"]
```